# file format is incorrect in PHPExcel Code

Tags: phpexcel

I am trying to write `mySQL` data into `Exlcel` using `PHPExcel`, but I am getting file format is invalid in my above `PHP` code using `PHPExcel`. Can someone please help me to find out what is wrong in code:

```
$query = "SELECT company_id, userid FROM uam_user";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in Query".mysql_error());
    // Instantiate a new PHPExcel object 
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();  

    // Set document properties 
        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Security Team") 
         ->setLastModifiedBy("System") 
         ->setTitle("System") 
         ->setSubject("System Security") 
         ->setDescription("Non Production user Upload Data") 
         ->setKeywords("User Upload") 
         ->setCategory("Security"); 


            // Set the active Excel worksheet to sheet 0 
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0); 

                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("A1", 'company_id');
         $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("B2", 'userid');

    //start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields  
    $rowCount = 2;
    //$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    //echo $num_rows;
    $i = 0;
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

        if ($row['userid'] != '')
        {
            //echo "A$rowCount=".$row['company_id']."|B$rowCount=".$row['userid']."<br>";
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("A$rowCount",$row['company_id']);
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("B$rowCount",$row['userid']);
         }
      $rowCount++;
      //echo $rowCount;
    }

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="item_list.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    ob_end_clean();
    $objWriter->save ( 'php://output' );
```

Comment: There is no need to shout for asking help..

Comment: Excel2007 writer is used to created an xlsx file, which should have a content type of `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`, not `application/vnd.ms-excel`

Comment: I have below header and same problem: header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'); header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.xlsx"'); header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');